# Deleting questions

Tags: support, status-completed, deleted-questions

How do I delete my question from Stack Overflow?

I have posted a question as an unregistered user by mistake, but now I would like to delete it.

Comment: @digonto - this will get migrated to meta.stackoverflow.com, where you should be able to find the answer already. You can also check the FAQ(s), one or more of which contain this info.

Answer (score 6):

Flag it for moderator attention, leaving a comment that explains why you want it deleted.

Comment: Or simply ask for it to be merged into your registered account.

Answer (score -2):

Huh? Isn't there a `delete` button when you view your question?

Comment: Only if no one has answered it yet. It stops being your question when you post it btw, and it becomes the community's.

Comment: You still get a `delete` button after posting the question, but there are rules about when you can delete something. In this case, however, the OP is looking specifically for a feature which would allow him to delete what is, according to the system, technically someone else's question -- he did the other post while not signed in.